# Passing from integration over hermitian matrices to integration over eigenvalues.

Tags: matrices, integration

Integral over hermitian matrices $\int dH$ in terms of matrix $H$ components $h_{ij}$ is defined by $$\int dH f(H)=\int \prod_idh_{ii}\prod_{i<j}d^2h_{ij} f(H)$$ Integrals over diagonal components are one-dimensional since these components are obligatory real for hermitian matrix and integrals over independent non-diagonal elements are two-dimensional. Any hermitian matrix $H$ can be diagonalized by means of some unitary matrix $U$ such that $H=UDU^\dagger$ with $D=diag\{d_1,...\}$ and $d_1,...$ being eigenvalues of $H$. As far as I know there is standard procedure to pass from integration over $h_{ij}$ to integration over $d_i$ and independent components of $U$,  $u_{ij}$. Such transformation is useful if one integrates function that is invariant with respect to such unitary transformations, say $f_{inv}(H)= Tr(H) $. My question is how exactly one performs this change of variables. Technically, my problem is that I don't know the convenient way to parametrize arbitrary unitary matrix and therefore how to compute Jacobian of this variable change. As far as I know for an invariant function $f_{inv}$ the result is something like
$$\int dH f_{inv}(H)\sim Vol(U)\int \prod_id_i \prod_{i<j}(d_i-d_j)^2f_{inv}(H)$$ 
where $Vol(U)$ is in a certain sense the "volume" of the group of unitary matrices and non-trivial factor being the Vandermonde determinant appeared.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?